# Is there a limit to the amount of questions you can ask on Meta in a specific time period?

Tags: support, meta

On the main site you can ask a maximum of 6 questions in a 24-hour period, and in a 30 day period, you have a maximum of 50 questions, I do not know if there are any other limits for years etc, but I assume not. But are there the same or similar limitations on Meta as I have never asked so many questions here to find out and I would probably greatly annoy everyone if I did an experiment to try and find out if there was a maximum number of questions that can be posted on Meta in a specific time period?

Comment: [Yep](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bz3kZ.png). At least one limit applies here, no reason why [the others](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/270345) wouldn't.

Comment: It does say the asking rate limit is "not active on all other sites" though. We could experiment (for science!) but it'd probably result in somebody getting an automated ask-ban after we cleaned up. Doesn't seem worth it.